# Show colors in output of bash script or bash -c

Tags: bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the new Bash shell on Windows 10, but I'm pretty sure this happens on all platforms.

```
 $ ls
a.out
```

`a.out` would be green.

---

```
 $ bash -c "ls"
a.out
```

Here, `a.out` is normal colored.

How do I get the second case to behave like the first?

Comment: `bash -ic "ls"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable colors:

```
 bash -c "ls --color=auto"
```

Try also:

```
bash -i -c ls
```

Comment: +1. Note that the reason for the difference is that the OP probably has `ls` aliased to `ls --color=auto`, but this alias is probably set in a login script that's only run when Bash starts in interactive mode, not in `bash -c ...`.

Comment: @ruakh Good point. I think that OP may try `bash -i -c ls` but not sure if that works (I can't test it right now)

Comment: The `-i` option was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!